# ¿No había un botón para descartar la respuesta?

Tags: soporte, interfaz-de-usuario

Pues eso. Son imaginaciones mías, o antes había un botón que ponía <kbd>Descartar</kbd> (o algo así).

Esto es lo que veo al escribir una respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igual es que tengo falta de cafeína, pero yo juraría que antes salía otro botón mas O_o

Comment: Sí, si que lo había.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El botón de descartar aparece cuando ha sido guardado un borrador, no aparece al momento, se supone que tarda unos 45 segundos. Aquí lo explican:

[What happened to the "discard" button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207723/what-happened-to-the-discard-button)

Espera un rato y lo verás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues si, tienes razón. Lo acabo de comprobar. Lo dicho, falta de cafeína :-)